# Nested div show and hide using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is works almost perfectly fine, but there are some issue with show and hide.

When I click on `How` and after that I click on `What` and then I click on `How` it show `How` children and `What` children as well, it should no do that.

And if I click on `How` and then `1.s` and then I click on `What` I would like to hide the third column as well, I do not have any idea, who could I possibly do that.

This code would be something like a menu system.

```js
$(".second").children().hide();

$(document).on("click", ".first li", function() {
  var firstClass = $(this).children("a").attr('class');
  $(".second").find('.' + firstClass).prev().hide();
  $(".second").find('.' + firstClass).show();
  
  $(document).on("click", ".second ."+firstClass+" li", function() {
    var season = $(this).children("a").index()+1;
    var episodeNumber = $(this).children("a").attr("value");
        var htmlCode = '';
    for(let i = 1; i <= episodeNumber; i++) {
        htmlCode += '<ul><li><a href=#>' + i + ".r" +'</a></li><ul>';
    }
    $(".third").find("." + firstClass).find("." + season).html(htmlCode);    
    });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
}
.first {
  width: 40vw;
}
.second {
  width: 20vw;
}
.third {
  width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="first">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="HowI">How</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Whater">What</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="second" >
    <div class="HowI">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" value="3">1. s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="1">2. s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="2">3. s</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="Whater">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" value="2">1. s</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="third">
      <div class="HowI">
        <div class="1"></div>
        <div class="2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="Whater">
        <div class="1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below snippet I used the approach of first hiding everything, then show the one thing you need to show. I first hid every child of .second than shown the one item clicked. Same for third. Note. that hiding all .third children ment that it is needed to first show the one .third child before you can search it's children.

```js
$(".second").children().hide();

$(document).on("click", ".first li", function() {
  var firstClass = $(this).children("a").attr('class');
  $(".second").children().hide();
  $(".third").children().hide();
  $(".second").find('.' + firstClass).show();

  $(document).on("click", ".second ."+firstClass+" li", function() 
  {
    var season = $(this).children("a").index()+1;
    var episodeNumber = $(this).children("a").attr("value");
        var htmlCode = '';
    for(let i = 1; i <= episodeNumber; i++) {
        htmlCode += '<ul><li><a href=#>' + i + ".r" +'</a></li><ul>';
    }
    $(".third").find("." + firstClass).show();
    $(".third").find("." + firstClass).find("." + season).html(htmlCode);    
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
}
.first {
  width: 40vw;
}
.second {
  width: 20vw;
}
.third {
  width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="first">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="HowI">How</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Whater">What</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="second" >
    <div class="HowI">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" value="3">1. s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="1">2. s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="2">3. s</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="Whater">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" value="2">1. s</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="third">
      <div class="HowI">
        <div class="1"></div>
        <div class="2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="Whater">
        <div class="1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```